# High performance memory kit for a fanless mini-itx home server based on a i9-10900T and a Gigabyte Z490I AORUS ULTRA?

Tags: memory, performance, compatibility, fanless, reliability

I am looking forward to build a fanless mini-ITX computer (with a dedicated computer case). The criteria that are important to me for this platform are the following:

1. **Reliability**: no system crash, no instability
2. **Durability**: long-term system stability (think of a home server running 24/7
   for years)
3. **Performance**: as high as possible given the energy constraints and that 1. and 2. are met

The rest of the platform will be:

- **CPU**: [Intel Core i9-10900T](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i9-processors/i9-10900t.html): 10 cores, 1.90 GhZ (4.60 GhZ Turbo), 35W TDP (as this processor can go up to 120W TDP when no limitation are put in place, I will put a TDP limit in the bios given that the platform will be fanless)
- **Motherboard**: [Gigabyte Mini-ITX Z490I AORUS ULTRA (rev. 1.x)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z490I-AORUS-ULTRA-rev-1x#kf), manual [here](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z490i-aorus-ultra_1001_e.pdf), official memory support list [here](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_z490i-aorus-ultra.pdf)

Given my criteria and my CPU and motherboard, I would like to know what would be the best **memory** that would fit my needs given the following constraints:

- **Type**: DDR4 DIMM (non-ECC)
- **Amount**: 64 GB (2x32 GB kit)
- **LED**: for equivalent kits performance-wise, without LEDs will be prefered
- **Voltage**: for equivalent kits performance-wise, the lower the better
- **Brand**: preferably one known for reliability, stability, and durability
- **Max price**: irrelevant in the limit of about 500 euros/dollars for the kit

Since I am looking for something extremely stable, I am unlikely to tweak a million options in the BIOS. Overclocking will not be a thing, since it will be for something that will be used as a fanless home server most of the time. But even with these constraints, I am looking for the best possible performance.

Any advice? I am looking for 2 or 3 good options that would fit my needs.